# When will Loki support end? (What date?)

Tags: release-loki, updates, elementary-project

What is the end support date for Loki? Will Loki follow Ubuntu's support dates?

Answer (score 3):

I guess it will have updates until next elementary OS release (0.5) but the backend (Ubuntu) will keep updating until EOL, which is IIRC in 2021

Answer (score 3):

The elementary team typically [only supports the latest release](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/22rhi3/how_long_is_luna_supported_for/) with feature updates, which I think is mainly a volunteer issue than anything else. The team tends to not set firm release dates and follows a "done when it's done" mentality. So now that Loki is released, there isn't a set date for Freya's end-of-life, but Freya-specific issues will likely not garner much attention. You can track the progress on the next release, Juno, [here](https://launchpad.net/elementary/+milestone/juno-beta1). That will likely be as close as it gets to Loki's end-of-life.

The OS is built atop Ubuntu "Long Term Support" releases, which also stop receiving feature support after about nine months but do receive major security fixes for five years ([April 2021](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Table_of_versions)). The team pushes those security updates to former releases and will post in a public place if for some reason an older release cannot update (users would be expected to upgrade for security reasons at that time).